# Question regarding matrix having minimal polynomial $X^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Let $P$ be a $4\times 4$ matrix. Let $x^2$ be the minimal polynomial of $A$. Is $A$ diagonalizable?

Efforts:

$x^2$ is the minimal polynomial, so $A^2=0$. It implies that $A$ is nilpotent matrix. Now we can take any non zero nilpotent matrix and it will suffice.
Am I right?

Thanks for reading. 
Feel free to correct the English language errors(in case it is unreadable).

Comment: Think of all possible Jordan forms, and find a non-diagonalizable one.

Comment: Let $A$ be a matrix such that $a_{12}=0$ and rest entries  are equal to $0$.  This will be adequate right? Thanks for the hint.@PedroTamaroff

Comment: I think you mean $a_{12}=1$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Yeah. You are right. Thanks for the quick assistance. Have a good day.

Comment: I wrote an answer, can you accept it?

Comment: Recall that the minimal polynomial must factor into _distinct_ linear terms for diagonalizability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false, and the fact that $A$ is nilpotent of order $2$ points to a counterexample rather quickly:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$